# Unknown error writing an array to an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking to add an array to a div. Not working with `document.getElementsByClassName('boxed').innerHTML = numList`. I am able to write the array to the DOM with `document.write(numList)`.
Here's the whole HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Super Lotto</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="lotto-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
    do {
        var high = prompt('What\'s the highest number you want to generate','');
        high = parseInt(high, 10);
    } while (isNaN(high));

    do {
        var nums = prompt('How many numbers do you want to generate','');
        nums = parseInt(nums, 10);
    } while (isNaN(nums));


    function rand(highestNum) {
        var randomNumber =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * highestNum) + 1;
        return randomNumber;
    }

    var numList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
        // Go through this loop quantity of times
        numList.unshift(rand(high)); 
        // add new number to end of array
    };
    numList.toString();
    document.getElementsByClassName('boxed').innerHTML = numList;
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Lucky Numbers</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="boxed"></div>
         <p>Good luck!</p>
    </main>
</div> <!-- Closing container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that in innerHTML you can't add an array, just a string, to add the numbers you need to do something like `numList.join(" ");`, I modified your code to do that. another thing I change is that instead of use "boxed" as a class, I use it as an id because getElementsByClassName return an nodeList.

```js
 do {
    var high = prompt('What\'s the highest number you want to generate','');
    high = parseInt(high, 10);
} while (isNaN(high));

do {
    var nums = prompt('How many numbers do you want to generate','');
    nums = parseInt(nums, 10);
} while (isNaN(nums));


function rand(highestNum) {
    var randomNumber =
    Math.floor(Math.random() * highestNum) + 1;
    return randomNumber;
}

var numList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
    // Go through this loop quantity of times
    numList.unshift(rand(high)); 
    // add new number to end of array
};

numList.toString();
document.getElementById('boxed').innerHTML = numList.join(" ");
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Lucky Numbers</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div id="boxed"></div>
         <p>Good luck!</p>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the div selector to an Id as recommended - the result was similar with the array still not present. In the console it stated `TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function`.

Comment: this is because is documet.getElementById, and you are doing getElementSById, if you change this. the error will be gone

Comment: Thank you, the result is `document.getElementById(...) is null`

Comment: you change the div from class to id?, from class="boxed" to id="boxed"?,

Comment: Sorry not to mention before, yes I did.

Comment: you can upload your code to codesanbox or something like that?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-leaf-oqdt3?file=/index.html

Comment: Your problem is that the JS is executed before the HTML is in the DOM, and for this reason the result of getElementById is incorrect, The solution is set the <script> tag behind the <body>, you can check this here https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-jennings-v1eo5

Comment:  Thank you! I've been working with JQuery's `$(document).ready()` most of the semester and overlooked this.

Answer (score 0):

When you get elements by class names (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), you receive an array,so you have to precise which element of the array you want, I think [0] in your case.
It's better to work with an ID if you only have one place to put the result, like this:

```js
    do {
        var high = prompt('What\'s the highest number you want to generate','');
        high = parseInt(high, 10);
    } while (isNaN(high));

    do {
        var nums = prompt('How many numbers do you want to generate','');
        nums = parseInt(nums, 10);
    } while (isNaN(nums));


    function rand(highestNum) {
        var randomNumber =
        Math.floor(Math.random() * highestNum) + 1;
        return randomNumber;
    }

    var numList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < nums; i++) {
        // Go through this loop quantity of times
        numList.unshift(rand(high)); 
        // add new number to end of array
        console.log(numList)
    };
    numList.toString();
    document.getElementById('boxed').innerHTML = numList;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Super Lotto</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="lotto-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Lucky Numbers</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div id="boxed"></div>
         <p>Good luck!</p>
    </main>
</div> <!-- Closing container -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I changed the div selector to an Id as recommended - the result was similar with the array still not present. In the console it stated `TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function`. Thanks for the response.